# Using kafka to produce data for clickhouse

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I want to use kafka integration for clickhouse. I tried to use official tutorial like [here](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/operations/table_engines/kafka/)! All table has been created. I run kafka server. Next run kafka producer and write in command promt json object like row in database. Like this:

```
{"timestamp":1554138000,"level":"first","message":"abc"}
```

I checked kafka consumer.It received object. But when I cheked tables in my clickhouse database there were empty rows. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: So basically, you were successfully put and get data from kafka. Now, where are your table ? I think you need a way to put data from Kafka to database.

Comment: table with engine kafka must consume data: 
   ```CREATE TABLE queue ( timestamp UInt64,
    level String,
    message String
  ) ENGINE = Kafka('localhost:9092', 'topic', 'group1', 'JSONEachRow');```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

To ignore malformed messages pass [kafka_skip_broken_messages](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/kafka/#table_engine-kafka-creating-a-table)-param to table definition.

---

It looks like a [well-known issue](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/4529) that occurred in one of the latest version of CH, try to add extra parameter **kafka_row_delimiter** to engine configuration:

```sql
CREATE TABLE queue (
 timestamp UInt64,
 level String,
 message String
) 
ENGINE = Kafka SETTINGS
  kafka_broker_list = 'localhost:9092',
  kafka_topic_list = 'topic',
  kafka_group_name = 'group1',
  kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow',
  kafka_row_delimiter = '\n'
  kafka_skip_broken_messages = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it did not support. Maybe I need change kafka configuration to send messages into clickhouse?

Comment: Let's look at logs **/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log**.

Answer (score 2):

So sorry. There was my fail. Before starting clickhouse and kafka. I tested sending simple messages into topic by kafka. And clickhouse tried parse it. I just create new topic and now everytning works. Thank you!