# Data pipeline 'MSSQL -> Kafka -> CH' not work

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, clickhouse

I created a JDBC-connection to SQL Server in Kafka and data is successfully loaded into the topic.

```sh
/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-testsql-topic --from-beginning
```

How can I read this topic in Clickhouse?

I created a new table with engine Kafka(on this topic) and materialized view, but unsuccessfully.

CH scripts:

```sh
CREATE TABLE default.test_topic (Id UInt32, Name FixedString(100)) 
ENGINE = Kafka 
SETTINGS 
    kafka_broker_list = localhost:9092, 
    kafka_topic_list = my-testsql-topic, 
    kafka_group_name = test-consumer-group, 
    kafka_format = JSONEachRow, 
    kafka_skip_broken_messages = 99999 

CREATE TABLE default.test_topic_hist (Id UInt32, Name FixedString(100)) 
ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY Id SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192 

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW default.load_test_topic_hist TO default.test_topic_hist (Id UInt32, Name FixedString(100)) AS 
SELECT Id, Name FROM default.test_topic
```

describe group:

```sh
GROUP                TOPIC              PARTITION    CURRENT-OFFSET   LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG 
test-consumer-group  my-testsql-topic   0            -                0               -
```

clickhouse-server.log:

```sh
2020.05.21 12:07:35.704680 [ 11942 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Already subscribed to topics: [ my-testsql-topic ] 
2020.05.21 12:07:35.704697 [ 11942 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Already assigned to : [ my-testsql-topic[0:#] ]    
2020.05.21 12:22:36.898540 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Stalled 
2020.05.21 12:22:36.898729 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Polled offset INVALID (topic: my-testsql-topic, partition: 0) 
2020.05.21 12:22:36.898741 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Nothing to commit. 
2020.05.21 12:22:36.899433 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Committed offset INVALID (topic: my-testsql-topic, partition: 0) 
2020.05.21 12:22:36.899504 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Execution took 501 ms.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using kafka to produce data for clickhouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457726/using-kafka-to-produce-data-for-clickhouse)

Comment: 1) could you provide the SQL-scripts for MV and Kafka-table in CH. 2) check the error log - */var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log* & provide description of related errors. 3) probably the reason is that the offset of consumer (that used Kafka-engine) is set to the latest position; try to insert a new row to MSQL & check related CH table

Comment: are you sure that you required the Kafka? CH supports connection as [ODBC](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/odbc/) as [JDBC](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/jdbc/) datasources.

Comment: CH scripts: `CREATE TABLE default.test_topic (Id UInt32, Name FixedString(100)) 
ENGINE = Kafka SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = localhost:9092, kafka_topic_list = my-testsql-topic, kafka_group_name = test-consumer-group, kafka_format = JSONEachRow, kafka_skip_broken_messages = 99999
CREATE TABLE default.test_topic_hist (Id UInt32, Name FixedString(100)) ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY Id SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW default.load_test_topic_hist TO default.test_topic_hist (Id UInt32, Name FixedString(100)) AS SELECT Id, Name FROM default.test_topic`

Comment: describe group:

`GROUP               TOPIC                    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG            
test-consumer-group my-testsql-topic         0          -               0               -   `

Comment: clickhouse-server.log:

`2020.05.21 12:07:35.704680 [ 11942 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): 
Already subscribed to topics: [ my-testsql-topic ]`
`2020.05.21 12:07:35.704697 [ 11942 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Already assigned to : [ my-testsql-topic[0:#] ]`

Comment: `2020.05.21 12:22:36.898540 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Stalled
2020.05.21 12:22:36.898729 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Polled offset INVALID (topic: my-testsql-topic, partition: 0)
2020.05.21 12:22:36.898741 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Nothing to commit.
2020.05.21 12:22:36.899433 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Committed offset INVALID (topic: my-testsql-topic, partition: 0)
2020.05.21 12:22:36.899504 [ 11946 ] {} <Trace> StorageKafka (test_topic): Execution took 501 ms.`

Comment: sorry, could you move the scripts & other info from the above comments to your question (and format them to ease reading)?

Comment: please provide the log *clickhouse-server.err.log* (not only *clickhouse-server.log*). Look at this [ClickHouse Kafka Engine FAQ](https://www.altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq)..

Comment: I'm find error:  IRowInputFormat: Skipped 1 rows with errors while reading the input stream

Comment: What format is the data recorded in kafka by jdbc connector?

Answer (score 1):

in jdbc config need add:

```sh
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```